# Adding multiple items to an action listener

Tags: java, jcombobox, jcheckbox

I was wondering in someone could point me in the right direction for this. I have this simple calculator, where the user enters two numbers and then has to select an action (+, -, *, *) from a drop down menu.

After they select an option, it gives them an answer, but I was trying to add a check box to allow the result to be displayed as a float if the box was checked. I was confused on how to have the `actionPreformed` handle both the `JCheckBox` and the `JComboBox`. I tried just adding `newCheckBox`, but that causes casting errors, between `JCheckBox` and `JComboBox`.

```
public class Calculator2 implements ActionListener {
private JFrame frame;
private JTextField xfield, yfield;
private JLabel result;
private JPanel xpanel;
String[] mathStrings = { "Multiply", "Subtraction", "Division", "Addition"};  //Options for drop down menu
JComboBox mathList = new JComboBox(mathStrings);                              //Create drop down menu and fill it

public Calculator2() {      
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    xpanel = new JPanel();
    xpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));

    xpanel.add(new JLabel("x:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
    xfield = new JTextField("0", 5);
    xpanel.add(xfield);

    xpanel.add(new JLabel("y:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
    yfield = new JTextField("0", 5);
    xpanel.add(yfield);

    xpanel.add(new JLabel("Result:"));
    result = new JLabel("0");
    xpanel.add(result);
    frame.add(xpanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);


    JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();                      //New panel for the drop down menu
    southPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

    JCheckBox newCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Show My Answer In Floating Point Format");  //Check box to allow user to view answer in floating point
    southPanel.add(newCheckBox);
 //newCheckBox.addActionListener(this);

    southPanel.add(mathList);
    mathList.addActionListener(this);

    frame.add(southPanel , BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    Font thisFont = result.getFont();                                       //Get current font
    result.setFont(thisFont.deriveFont(thisFont.getStyle() ^ Font.BOLD));   //Make the result bold
    result.setForeground(Color.red);                                        //Male the result answer red in color
    result.setBackground(Color.yellow);                                     //Make result background yellow
    result.setOpaque(true);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { 
    String xText = xfield.getText();                        //Get the JLabel fiels and set them to strings
    String yText = yfield.getText();

    int xVal;
    int yVal;

    try {
        xVal = Integer.parseInt(xText);                     //Set global var xVal to incoming string
        yVal = Integer.parseInt(yText);                     //Set global var yVal to incoming string
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {                       //xVal or yVal werent valid integers, print message and don't continue
        result.setText("ERROR");
        //clear();
        return ;
    } 

    JComboBox comboSource = (JComboBox)event.getSource();   //Get the item picked from the drop down menu
    String selectedItem = (String)comboSource.getSelectedItem();

    if(selectedItem.equalsIgnoreCase("Multiply")) {                  //multiply selected
        result.setText(Integer.toString(xVal*yVal)); 
    }
    else if(selectedItem.equalsIgnoreCase("Division")) {            //division selected
        if(yVal == 0) {                                   //Is the yVal (bottom number) 0?
            result.setForeground(Color.red);              //Yes it is, print message
            result.setText("CAN'T DIVIDE BY ZERO!");
            //clear();
        }
        else          
            result.setText(Integer.toString(xVal/yVal));  //No it's not, do the math
    }
    else if(selectedItem.equalsIgnoreCase("Subtraction")) {        //subtraction selected                                         
        result.setText(Integer.toString(xVal-yVal)); 
    }
    else if(selectedItem.equalsIgnoreCase("Addition")) {           //addition selected
        result.setText(Integer.toString(xVal+yVal)); 
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would recommend is that you keep a reference to the JCheckBox in the Calculator2 class.  So something along the lines of

```
public class Calculator implements ActionListener {
     ...
     JComboBox mathList = ...
     JCheckBox useFloatCheckBox = ...
     ...
}
```

then in your actionPerformed mehtod, instead of getting the reference to the widget from event.getSource() get it directly from the reference in the class.  So actionPerformed would look like this

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     String operator = (String)this.mathList.getSelected();
     boolean useFloat = this.useFloatCheckBox.isSelected();    
     ...
}
```

This way you can use the same listener on both objects without having to worry about casting the widget.

Answer (score 0):

The casting errors are because `event.getSource()` changes depending on which object fired the event. You can check the source of the event and process based on that:

```
if (event.getSource() instanceof JCheckBox) { ... act accordingly ... } else
```

Instead you could add a different ActionListener implementation to the JCheckBox so that the event it creates goes to a different place. An anonymous listener that sets a flag or calls a different method would work too.

There are other ways you could approach the problem, do you want the checkbox to affect an existing calculation, or only a new one? If only a new calculation you don't need an action listener on the checkbox, you can find out whether it is checked when you do the calculation:

```
if (myCheckbox.isSelected()) {
    // do float calculation...
} else {
    // do int calculation
}
```